# Startup times for different versions of tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8, tomcat6, tomcat5.5

Over time I have come to know that older java ee servers used to take tens of minutes to start up. If we consider tomcat for instance. Is there a comparison available about average statrtup time of each version of tomcat.

Comment: Starting a J2EE server alone is probably not worth to benchmark. Time taken is mostly due to deployed applications startup. Add to that the technology evolution in terms of CPU/memory/networking and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The startup time has more to do with your application than tomcat. If you're running different apps with lots of spring beans or some other dependency injection framework then its the load time of your dependencies that is the real bottleneck.